# Random byte string in Python

Tags: python, string, random, hex

I have `buf="\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x00"`

How can I make the `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"` randomized?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> "\x00"+os.urandom(4)+"\x00"
'\x00!\xc0zK\x00'
```

Comment: i just check the python doc..
whats different with ''.join(chr(random.randint(0,255)) for _ in range(4))

Comment: @zack, apart from being more efficent, randint returns **pseudo-random** numbers. urandom returns random bytes that are suitable for **cryptographic use**

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Unless `/dev/urandom` is using some hardware random number generator, its numbers are also pseudo-random. A deterministic machine will always generate pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: @NullUserException, see `urandom`[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#miscellaneous-functions) `/dev/random` is a more random source of randomness, but blocks whenever there is not enough entropy.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I don't know how this addresses my comment. I'm just saying `/dev/random` (and also `/dev/urandom`) are pseudorandom number generators, just like `randint`. A CSPRNG is still pseudo-random. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635277/is-dev-random-considered-truly-random).

Comment: @NullUserException /dev/urandom isn't guaranteed to be pseudo-random since there is hardware to generate random numbers and it will leverage that hardware as a factor in generating the it's resulting strings.

If the choice is only between a guaranteed pseudo-random number generator or a potentially truly-random number generator, I'd think we'd always want to go with the potentially truly random one. I think?

Comment: @NullUserException On Linux, /dev/random uses known sources of entropy as input, including (but not limited to) human users's movements of the mouse, environmental noise, etc. Although the kernel in and of itself is deterministic, the combination kernel+human+environment is not.

Answer (score 40):

An alternative way to obtaining a secure random sequence of bytes could be to use the standard library `secrets` module, available since Python 3.6.

Example, based on the given question:

```
import secrets
b"\x00" + secrets.token_bytes(4) + b"\x00"
```

More information can be found at:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Answer (score 30):

```
bytearray(random.getrandbits(8) for _ in xrange(size))
```

Faster than other solutions but not cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 25):

Python 3.9 adds a new [`random.randbytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.randbytes) method. This method generates random bytes:

```
from random import randbytes

randbytes(4)
```

Output:

```
b'\xf3\xf5\xf8\x98'
```

Be careful though. It should be used only when you are not dealing with cryptography. As stated in the docs:

> This method should not be used for generating security tokens. Use [`secrets.token_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_bytes) instead.

Comment: One cool thing about this is that allows setting a seed for deterministic testing with `random.seed`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329381/generating-random-string-of-seedable-data/66018128#66018128

Answer (score 8):

On POSIX platforms:

```
open("/dev/urandom","rb").read(4)
```

Use `/dev/random` for better randomization.

Comment: in practice, this is about 2.5 times faster than os.urandom if you leave the file descriptor open between calls. useful for random guesses at nonces for cryptocurrency hashes.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Why would you use os.urandom if you don't need it to be cryptographically secure - there are much faster `prng`'s than os.urandom.

Comment: @user3467349 To be fair, urandom is potentially truly random and not only PRNG

Answer (score 7):

Do you want the middle 4 bytes to be set to a random value?

```
buf = '\x00' + ''.join(chr(random.randint(0,255)) for _ in range(4)) + '\x00'
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be used to generate a string of random bytes (replace `n` with the desired amount):

```
import random
random_bytes = bytes([random.randrange(0, 256) for _ in range(0, n)])
-or-
random_bytes = bytes([random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(0, n)])
-or-
random_bytes = bytes([random.getrandbits(8) for _ in range(0, n)])
```

The answer to the specific question would then be:

```
import random
buf = b'\x00' + bytes([random.randrange(0, 256) for _ in range(0, 4)]) + b'\x00'
-or-
buf = b'\x00' + bytes([random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(0, 4)]) + b'\x00'
-or-
buf = b'\x00' + bytes([random.getrandbits(8) for _ in range(0, 4)]) + b'\x00'
```

As others pointed out, this should not be used for cryptography, but for everything else it should be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

I like using numpy library for that.

```
import numpy as np

X_1KB = 1024
X_256KB = 256 * X_1KB
X_1MB = 1024 * 1024
X_4MB = 4 * X_1MB
X_32MB = 32 * X_1MB
X_64MB = 2 * X_32MB
X_128MB = X_1MB * 128


np.random.bytes( X_1MB )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
import functools, random, operator
functools.reduce(operator.add, ('%c' % random.randint(0, 255) for i in range(4)))
```

Comment: That will return a string representation of a list, not a string as the OP asked.

Comment: `"".join(...)` is the preferred way to turn a sequence into a string

Answer (score -2):

```
from random import randint 
rstr = ''.join( randint(0, 255) for i in range(4) )
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'buf' is not defined`

Comment: Comment by anonymous user: You can't join anything but a list of strings into a `string` so change the `int` to `string` character. Code: `rstr = "".join( chr(randint(0, 255)) for i in range(4))`.

Comment: Typical example of a poor answer. No explanation of functionality, of your code, or of reasons why this solution is effective. I did not vote you down, but I can see why others did. However, you are not alone, it seems many do this and I feel it reduces the quality of SO.